# How to use conditional format in Epplus?

Tags: asp.net, excel, epplus

I want to set conditional format for empty values , how can i do it in asp.net ?

Screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support for conditional formatting in EPPlus but you can add it by modifiyng the XML code yourself. Take a look at the source-code here: http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/348196/

Answer (score 6):

There is support for conditional formatting in the 3.1 beta version of EPPlus. It can be downloaded from [epplus.codeplex.com](http://epplus.codeplex.com) or via nuget (use the -pre flag). Check out the sample project ("downloads" on epplus.codeplex.com) for a detailed description of how to use it.